# Permutation as an adjective?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, grammar, adjectives

**"My studies showcase special emphasis on cumulative recursive [permutative?] effects of one's hydration, nutrition, self-image, and general cognitive ability."**

Basically, each of the four items affects any number of the others, which in turn affects any number of its others...

I would like to describe that each one has an effect that continuously affects the way that one or more or all the others affect it and each other one, which in turn again further ....

recursive permutations seems about right, but I would love to describe the subject 'effects' with a variation of 'permutations' used with 'recursive' as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should try something simpler:

> My studies emphasize the effects resulting from the relationships between one's hydration,
>   nutrition, self-image, and general cognitive ability.

But perhaps you may just want the word "permuted".

Comment: hmm. So simple... and I feel it really does do all the hard work for me. Very well done! Would my adding the word 'continuing' add or detract at this point? "My studies emphasize the continuing effects resulting from the relationships between one's hydration, nutrition, self-image, and general cognitive ability." I would really like the point that the way one affects the other now has a significant compound effect on how all the others will continue to affect the others, ad infinitum...

Comment: @ProductionValues Not bad, but you may want to say "ongoing effects"